# AppUriHandler cannot deploy on Windows Phone 10 (UWP)

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile, appxmanifest

I have a **UWP Store App** and try to use web-to-app linking using the AppUriHandler in the **Package.appxmanifest**.
It seems to work well on the desktop but I am getting a deployment error on **Windows Phone 10**:
DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2146958844

The error disappears when I remove the uap3:Extension

```
<Package  
...  
xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"  
IgnorableNamespaces="... uap3">  
...  
<Applications>  
<Application>  
  <Extensions>  
    <uap3:Extension Category="windows.appUriHandler">  
      <uap3:AppUriHandler>  
        <uap3:Host Name="mydomain.comunity.me" />  
      </uap3:AppUriHandler>  
    </uap3:Extension>  
  </Extensions>
```

I based my manifest on the following posts:
[Support web-to-app linking with app URI handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking)
[uap3:AppUriHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt670665.aspx)

edit (6 Apr 2017)
This is a **WinRT** App using **C++/CX**
I got the above error when deploying (x86) to the **Mobile Emulator** 10.0.14393.0...

Deploying (ARM) to **Microsoft Lumia 550**, V1607, OS build 10.0.14393.953, I got a different error...

Visual Studio 2015 Output...

```
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...  
2>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/ARM, app package version  
14.0.25017.0 is not currently installed.  
2>Installing missing frameworks...  
2>Registering the application to run from layout...  
2>DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009287  
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========  
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

(Visual Studio 2017 produces exactly the same errors)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide environment information, such as your uwp app version, your windows phone 10 OS version, and a reproduce project will be much better. Also please try it on emulator if it is work. If you have conditions, please try another phone.

Comment: Checkout the edited version